# Bit shifting and bit mask - sample code

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

I've come across some code which has the bit masks `0xff` and `0xff00` or in 16 bit binary form `00000000 11111111` and `11111111 00000000`.

```
/**
 * Function to check if the given string is in GZIP Format.
 *
 * @param inString String to check.
 * @return True if GZIP Compressed otherwise false.
 */
public static boolean isStringCompressed(String inString)
{
    try
    {
        byte[] bytes = inString.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
        int gzipHeader = ((int) bytes[0] & 0xff)
            | ((bytes[1] << 8) & 0xff00);
        return GZIPInputStream.GZIP_MAGIC == gzipHeader;
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to work out what the purpose of using these bit masks in this context (against a byte array). I can't see what difference it would make?

In the context of a GZip compressed string as this method seems to be written for the GZip magic number is `35615`, `8B1F` in Hex and `10001011 00011111` in binary.

Am I correct in thinking this swaps the bytes? So for example say my input string were `\u001f\u008b`

```
bytes[0] & 0xff00
 bytes[0] = 1f = 00011111
          & ff = 11111111
                 --------
               = 00011111

bytes[1] << 8
 bytes[1] = 8b = 10001011
          << 8 = 10001011 00000000

((bytes[1] << 8) & 0xff00)
= 10001011 00000000 & 0xff00
= 10001011 00000000 
  11111111 00000000 &
-------------------
  10001011 00000000
```

So

```
00000000 00011111
10001011 00000000 |
-----------------
10001011 00011111 = 8B1F
```

To me it doesn't seem like the `&` is doing anything to the original byte in both cases `bytes[0] & 0xff` and `(bytes[1] << 8) & 0xff00)`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
int gzipHeader = ((int) bytes[0] & 0xff) | ((bytes[1] << 8) & 0xff00);
```

The type `byte` is Java is *signed*. If you cast a `byte` to an `int`, its [sign will be extended](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_extension). The `& 0xff` is to mask out the `1` bits that you get from sign extension, effectively treating the `byte` as if it is unsigned.

Likewise for `0xff00`, except that the byte is first shifted 8 bits to the left.

So, what this does is:

- take the first byte, `bytes[0]`, cast it to `int` and mask out the sign-extended bits (treating the byte as if it is unsigned)
- take the second byte, cast it to `int`, shift it left by 8 bits, and mask out the sign-extended bits
- combine the values with `|`

Note that the shift left effectively swaps the bytes.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the purpose is to read the first word of `bytes` and store them in `gzipHeader` by suitable masking and shifting. More precisely, the first part masks out exactly the first byte while the second part masks out the second byte, already shifted by 8 bits. The `|` combines both bit masks to an `int`.

The resulting value is compared against the defined value `GZIPInputStream.GZIP_MAGIC` to determine if the first two bytes are the defined beginning of data compressed with gzip.

Answer (score 1):

This is a trick to overcome [big-endian/little-endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) issues. It is forcing the interpretation of the first two bytes as little-endian, i.e. `[0]` contains the `low` byte and `[1]` contains the `high` byte.

Answer (score 0):

`byte` is a signed type. If you convert 0xff as a `byte` to `int` you get -1. If you actually want to get 255, mask after the conversion.