# Is there a way to write groups of bits less than a byte in Java

Tags: java, file, dataoutputstream

If I was to try to make a program that outputs .Flac files in Java, [Flac-format](https://xiph.org/flac/format.html#metadata_block_header),
It appears that I would need to output values less than a byte. Is it even possible to output values less than a byte such as a nybble or a 5-bit number?

Comment: It's more likely you will need to set 5 bits of a whole byte. The search term you're looking for is "bit mask".

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30327937/bit-shifting-and-bit-mask-sample-code) for example.

Comment: I presume you'll have to write bits (represented as bools, for example) and then turn these into bytes. I have a personal utility class (BitAssembler) to which you push bits, and from which you can pop assembled bytes. https://github.com/nylanderdev/nylander-utils Just remember that you need to push 8 bits for each byte you pop, so you'll have to add trailing or leading padding bits yourself.

Comment: As you can see the 5 bit number is preceeded by a 3 bit number, which adds up to 8 bits, or one byte. So you'll want to push 3 bits, then 5 bits, and pop the resulting byte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I think I can do this using bit shifting and logical commands such as & and | opperators.

Answer (score 1):

[ImageOutputStream.writeBits](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/imageio/stream/ImageOutputStream.html#writeBits(long,int)) should do what you want.

You create an ImageOutputStream using the [ImageIO.createImageOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#createImageOutputStream(java.lang.Object)) method:

```
Path flacPath = Paths.get(filename);

try (ImageOutputStream out = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(
    new BufferedOutputStream(Files.newOutputStream(flacPath)))) {

    out.writeBits(0b1110101011, 10);
    // etc.
}
```